# Pig - Remove line feed, return and tab

Tags: regex, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to remove the characters: \n, \t and \r from a column in Pig but I'm getting the wrong output.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
qr_1 = LOAD 'hdfs://localhost:9000/sample.csv' USING PigStorage(',') as (Id:int,PostTypeId:int,AcceptedAnswerId:int,ParentId:int,CreationDate:chararray,DeletionDate:chararray,Score:int,ViewCount:int,Body:chararray,OwnerUserId:int,OwnerDisplayName:chararray,LastEditorUserId:int,LastEditorDisplayName:chararray,LastEditDate:chararray,LastActivityDate:chararray,Title:chararray,Tags:chararray,AnswerCount:int,CommentCount:int,FavoriteCount:int,ClosedDate:chararray,CommunityOwnedDate:chararray);
qr_1 = FOREACH qr_1 GENERATE Id .. ViewCount, REPLACE(Body,'\n','') as Body, OwnerUserId .. ;
qr_1 = FOREACH qr_1 GENERATE Id .. ViewCount, REPLACE(Body,'\r','') as Body, OwnerUserId .. ;   
qr_1 = FOREACH qr_1 GENERATE Id .. ViewCount, REPLACE(Body,'\t','') as Body, OwnerUserId .. ;
```

Input:

```
5585779,1,5585800,,2011-04-07 18:27:54,,1432,3090250,"<p>How can I convert a <code>String</code> to an <code>int</code> in Java?</p>

<p>My String contains only numbers and I want to return the number it represents.</p>

<p>For example, given the string <code>""""1234""""</code> the result should be the number <code>1234</code>.</p>",537967,,2756409,user166390,2015-09-10 21:30:42,2016-03-07 00:42:49,Converting String to Int in Java?,<java><string><type-conversion>,12,0,239
```

Output:

```
(5585779,1,5585800,,2011-04-07 18:27:54,,1432,3090250,"<p>How can I convert a <code>String</code> to an <code>int</code> in Java?</p>,,,,,,,,,,,,,)
(,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)
(,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)
(,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)
(,,537967,,2756409,user166390,,,Converting String to Int in Java?,,12,0,239,,,,,,,,,)
```

What am I doing?

Thanks.

Also "\\n" doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Why can't you read the data in by lines first, then split on the commas?

Comment: @cricket_007 because the Body column contains line breaks.

Comment: Couldn't you body column contain commas?

Comment: It contains commas, \\n and \\r. I want to remove them so that Pig doesn't split the Body column into multiple parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is comma in your data and that's why the fields and the schema are not matching.Use [CSVLoader](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVLoader.html) and then use the REPLACE command to replace '\\t','\\n','\\r'

```
<p>For example, given the string
```